# How can I center Openlayers div on screen?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a div centered on screen (using width:75%;height:50%;margin: 0 auto;)
When I init the map div with OL , it auto aligned to the left.
How can I keep having the div in the center of the window?

Comment: Have you tried using a child div to hold the map?

Answer (score 1):

Your div containing map must be positioned absolutely. If you know the required height and width of your map, it could be as follows:

```
  #map{
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -150px!important; /*negative half of height*/
    margin-left: -200px!important; /*negative half of width*/
  }
```

Note the **!important** rule. It will override the default css properties set by OpenLayers. In case you are not sure about absolute height and width of your map div, you can use [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/). Calculate scrren width and height, and set css properties of map div from javascript.

Comment: thank you. what will happen when I resize the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Code

```
.centerDiv
{
    width: 75%;
    height:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="centerDiv">
</div>
```

Full source... [Div on center](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/center-div.html)